Solving scope issue while using jQuery ready function
How can I solve this scope issue:
I am trying to update an old project.
HTML file includes JS file.
after some code from the JS is running, it calls back a function myFunc() from the HTML.
In the new code, I need to add jQuery ready function to the HTML file.
so I get error
  jQuery.Deferred exception: myFunc is not defined 
  

what is the minimum change I can make in the JS code (or in the HTML code?) to solve this scope issue?
EDIT: all code must be in ready handler, because it depends on document ready
EDIT2: There are many functions in the HTML script, that call each other, so I cannot just change 'take out' only one function and put it outside the ready handler
my HTML file:
<html>
<head>
  ... html code ...
  <script src="/my.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  ... html code ...
  <script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {   // <- this line was added to the new HTML file
    ...
    function myFunc() {              // was called from JS file. but now is considered undefined :(
    ...
  }
  });                                // <- this line was added to the new HTML file
  </script>

</body>
</html>

my JS file:
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    myFunc();
    ...
  });

})(this.jQuery);


Why did you wrap the function definition in a ready handler?  If the function needs to be defined in global scope, define it in global scope.  It sounds like you simply made an errant change and the fix is to undo that change.

In addition to what @David said: Instead of removing .ready, attach the myFunc function to the window object via window.myFunc = function myFunc( ... (this happens anyway if you move it outside the function passed to .ready) and still get the benefit of (possibly) other definitions in the ready callback function not polluting the window object.

^--- True.  Alternatively, you could also declare let myFunc; globally and over-write it in the handler scope (same as above but the window. part wouldn't be necessary).  We don't really know what other things are being defined there or why it was decided to wrap it all in a handler.

I added the "ready" because other script commands depends on DOM ready, so I cannot just undo it

@Atara: All the (first) code shown does is define a function.  Why specifically does that operation need to happen in a document ready handler?  Perhaps this is more of an XY Problem…

Using your hints, I solved it by adding window global function and also changing the order of the scripts.
in my JS file:
window.myFunc(); // call a global function from another file // myFunc();

in my HTML file:
<body>
  ... html code ...
  <script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {   // <- this line was added to the new HTML file
    ...
    function myFunc() {              // called from JS file.  
    }
    window.myFunc = myFunc;...
  }
  });                                // <- this line was added to the new HTML file
  </script>
<script src="/my.js"></script>       // verify that window.myFunc is already declared


Just move it outside the  $( document ).ready
